# Find all limit cycles of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limit-cycles

I am currently trying to study for an exam and ran into a problem regarding limit cycles.

The question is to find all limit cycles of the following system of the differential equations:

$$\dot{x}=-y-\frac{x(x^2+y^2-2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$\dot{y}=x-\frac{y(x^2+y^2-2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

The problem also gave a hint, which is to compute $$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}$$ and observe that a limit cycle C must be the orbit of a periodic solution to the given system if it contains no equilibrium points.

So, I followed the hint and computed
$$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}=2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y}$$but, I got something messy and I am not sure what to do afterwards...

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. $\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+y^2)}{\mathrm{d}t}=2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y}=\dots=-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2-2)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you! I got up to there, but I am not sure what to do to find a limit cycle...

Comment: To conclude, you should also check that there are no equilibria on $x^2+y^2=2$. But this is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2-2) = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2-2)
$$

hence

$$
\frac 12 \frac{d}{dt}\ln(x^2+y^2-2) = -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

Here $x^2+y^2 = r^2$

[image]

Comment: From your hint, I got that the limit cycle is just x^2+y^2=2, is this right?

Comment: Yes. The limit cycle is at $r = \sqrt 2$